# A folder created with os.Mkdir() has incorrect permissions

Tags: go, permissions, directory

I am creating a folder in go using os.Mkdir(). While it does get created, it does not possess the permissions I expected it to.

Here is the code I used to create the directory:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "os"
)

func main() {
    err := os.Mkdir("/var/run/testdir", 0777)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("could not create dir: %s", err.Error())
        err = nil
    }
}
```

As I have given "0777" as parameter, I am excpecting the created dir to have full permissions for everybody. It however has:

```
drwxr-xr-x  2 root       root         40 Apr 27 11:43 testdir/
```

What am I getting wrong here?

Comment: Check your umask :-)

Comment: You can do this by typing `umask` (or `umask -S`) in your terminal. You can also experiment with setting a temporary one using `umask 077`

Comment: Read about how umasks works. Set the umask to 0 for the “expected” behaviour.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The actual permission that the created folder will get is the result of the permission you specify (`0777`) and the active `umask` of your process (the running Go program).

This is most likely why the created folder lacks write permission for group and other access.

You can read more about `umask` on [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Umask).

Comment: Peter, please be sure to read the [`umask(2)` manual page](http://linux.die.net/man/2/umask).